# How to Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: pagespeed, google-pagespeed

I have speedup my desktop to 82/100, but mobile speed is still 60/100. Can anybody recommend me some tips about improving the mobile speed to 80/100.

Here is link the my current Google PageSpeed Insights:
https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.lutonairporttaxis.co.uk%2F&tab=mobile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of things that you could do to improve the score of your application. As PageSpeed Insights suggests, you could turn on your compression. This is an easy win and will make a difference to your files sizes over the wire.

In terms of the render-blocking CSS, why don't you try and automate the process. There is a great plugin called [Grunt-Critical](https://github.com/bezoerb/grunt-critical) that will automatically extract and inline your Critical CSS for you. For more information, I recommend reading [this article](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/service/PrioritizeCriticalCss) about Critical CSS.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the Grunt-Critical plugin and it works perfectly :)