# How I can eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: javascript, css, .htaccess, render, blocking

I am checking my website speed check on https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/ 
and I am seeing some problems reported:

> Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content
>   Your page has 39 blocking script resources and 32 blocking CSS resources.
>   This causes a delay in rendering your page.

My website is in Wordpress and I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Google for "above-the-fold" and wordpress, you will get some ideas what happening

Comment: Edited question for clarity

Comment: as i have checked on surepaint.com.au website speed test

Comment: Check this thread. i think its help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30569474/how-to-eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css-in-above-the-fold-content